# Get number of digits in variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable pid (represents parent_id attribute of each li element) like "1","14","253",etc. I need to align the content of li to left and right.

Based on condition, if the parent id has an even number of digits, then align left, else align right.

How can I find out the number of digits in the pid variable using Javascript?

Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: What's wrong with `pid.length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of digits in numeric string in Javascript , the easiest way I can think of is use the [length](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5.1) property of String:

```
var pid = "123";
var numDigits = pid.length;
if(numDigits === parseFloat(numDigits)) {
 if(numDigits%2 === 0 ) {
  // even
 }
 else {
  // odd 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = '253';
alert(a.length);
```

Just in case your pid is not string, you will get **undefined**, you can use toString() to be on safer side.

Few tests:

```
var str1 = 253;
alert(str1.length); //will not work give undefined

var str3 = str1.toString();
alert(str3.length); // will work

var str2 = '253';
alert(str2.length); //will work
```

Hope this will help.

~K

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use length directly on a string.

```
var pid = "123";
pid.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have the variable, you can just check the length of the string representation.

The number of digits is then even if

```
pid.length % 2 == 0
```

Edit: Removed link

Comment: Don't link to w3schools, its a very unreliable source of information and should be avoided at all times.

See http://www.w3fools.com/